# WordPress/ACF: custom block type renders only once within array of posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hello to everyone and beforehand thank you for spending your time on my question and forgive me my bad English.

**Input**

An array of WP_Post objects provided by [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/)

```
$features = get_field("features") ?: [];
foreach ( $features as  $feature) {
    echo  apply_filters('the_content' , $feature["post"]->post_content);
}
```

**Expected output/behavior**

Rendered content with [custom blocks](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/) created with ACF

**Actual output/behavior**

Only one type of custom block rendered per array of posts.

As an example:
if the first post contains a custom accordion block, then for the following posts accordion block won't be rendered.

**My thoughts**

I think it is somehow related to the way that ACF handles the_content filter.
It feels like it works only one time per request-to-block  and after that, it is just ignoring encountered blocks in the future apply_filter calls

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a question, you shoud add a minimum information: could you add one sample of your input, output and expected output?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Thank you for replying to my question and pointing to errors in my question composition! Now it looks better.

Comment: The documentation says you would do

$features = get_field("features") ?: [];
foreach ( $features as  $feature) {
    echo  $feature;
}

But I am not 100% sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Tami Thank you for your response!. 
I'm trying to create a custom block that will contain multiple tabs. Each tab represents a custom post-type record that I want to display to the user.

All works fine except that other custom blocks created with ACF inside these posts don't behave as they should.

Comment: Ahhh... sorry, I have done many things with ACF but not blocks. 
Could it be that this block is missing a closing div tag or something like that?